# specific number between 100,110,120,130,140,150 in Android studio

Tags: android, random

I know we can generate numbers between 0-10 or 10-100 or even 100-100
Using (max-min)+min
But i want to generate numbers between 100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190.

Need suggestions.

Comment: Generate numbers between 10-100 and multiply by 10?

Comment: Sorry if you misunderstood my question. I am asking about random numbers we can chose between 0-10 or 10-100 which are continues number but i want to generate random numbers from specific number only.and this specific numbers are above numbers.

Comment: Is this a Java or Kotlin question? Typically you use the programming language as tag not the IDE (which is irrelevant as you can compile the project without it).

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin:

`arrayOf(100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190).random()`

Answer (score 0):

Just generate between 10 - 19 and multiply the result by 10

Comment: I have numbers like 579 which I can't get by multiplying. I have total no. 300 which are not in sequence thats why i am asking for help

Comment: @chintuboss your question is not clear to me at all. can you try to explain better?